# Docker swarm containers connection issues

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to use docker swarm to create simple nodejs service that lays behind Haproxy and connect to mysql. So, I created this docker compose file:

And I have several issues:

1. The backend service can't connect to the database using: localhost or 127.0.0.1, so, I managed to connect to the database using the private ip(10.0.1.4) of the database container.
2. The backend tries to connect to the database too soon even though it depends on it.
3. The application can't be reached from outside.

```html
    version: '3'

    services:
      db:
        image: test_db:01
        ports:
          - 3306
        networks:
          - db

    test:
        image: test-back:01
        ports:
          - 3000
        environment:
          - SERVICE_PORTS=3000
          - DATABASE_HOST=localhost
          - NODE_ENV=development
        deploy:
          replicas: 1
          update_config:
              parallelism: 1
              delay: 5s
          restart_policy:
              condition: on-failure
              max_attempts: 3
              window: 60s
        networks:
          - web
          - db
        depends_on:
          - db
        extra_hosts:
          - db:10.0.1.4

    proxy:
        image: dockercloud/haproxy
        depends_on:
          - test
        environment:
          - BALANCE=leastconn
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        ports:
          - 80:80
        networks:
          - web
        deploy:
          placement:
            constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
    web:
      driver: overlay
    db:
      driver: bridge
```

I am running the following:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml prod
```

All the services are running.

```
curl http://localhost/api/test <-- Not working
```

But, as I mentioned above the issues I have.

```
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
```

What do I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> The backend service can't connect to the database using: localhost or 127.0.0.1, so, I managed to connect to the database using the private ip(10.0.1.4) of the database container.

don't use IP addresses for connection. Use just the DNS name.
So you must change connection to `DATABASE_HOST=db`, because this is the service name you've defined.
Localhost is wrong, because the service is running in a different container as your `test` service.

> The backend tries to connect to the database too soon even though it depends on it.

`depends_on` does not work as you expected. Please read https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on and the info box `"There are several things to be aware of when using depends_on:"`
TL;DR: `depends_on` option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose file.

> The application can't be reached from outside.

Where is your haproxy configuration that it must request for `http://test:3000` when something requests haproxy on `/api/test`?

Comment: ok, I tried what you all suggest above and nothing worked also, can you suggest a good configuration that will work for this kind of stack?

Answer (score 0):

For `DATABASE_HOST=localhost` - the `localhost` word means my local container. You need to use the service name where db is hosted. `localhost` is a special dns name always pointing to the application host. when using containers - it will be the container. In cloud development, you need to forget about using localhost (will point to the container) or IPs (they can change every time you run the container and you will not be able to use load-balancing), and simply use service names.

As for the readiness - docker has no possibility of knowing, if the application you started in container is ready. You need to make the service aware of the database unavailability and code/script some mechanisms of polling/fault tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

Markus is correct, so follow his advice.

Here is a compose/stack file that should work assuming your app listens on port 3000 in the container and db is setup with proper password, database, etc. (you usually set these things as environment vars in compose based on their Docker Hub readme).

Your app should be designed to crash/restart/wait if it can't fine the DB. That's the nature of all distributed computing... that anything "remote" (another container, host, etc.) can't be assumed to always be available. If your app just crashes, that's fine and a normal process for Docker, which will re-create the Swarm Service task each time.

If you could attempt to make this with public Docker Hub images, I can try to test for you.

Note that in Swarm, it's likely easier to use Traefik for the proxy ([Traefik on Swarm Mode Guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/swarm-mode/)), which will autoupdate and route incoming requests to the correct container based on the hostname you give the labels... But note that you should test first just the app and db, then after you know that works, try adding in a proxy layer.

Also, in Swarm, all your networks should be overlay, and you don't need to specify as that is the default in stacks.

Below is a sample using traefik with your above settings. I didn't give the `test` service a specific traefik hostname so it should accept all traffic coming in on 80 and forward to 3000 on the test service.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: test_db:01
    networks:
      - db
  test:
    image: test-back:01
    environment:
      - SERVICE_PORTS=3000
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - web
      - db
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.port=3000
        - traefik.docker.network=web
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080" # traefik dashboard
    command:
      - --docker
      - --docker.swarmMode
      - --docker.domain=traefik
      - --docker.watch
      - --api
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
  web:
  db:
```